# Create column based on condition in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a new column in a SQLite database from Python. I would like the column to be either 1 or 0 if a criteria is met. I have tried the following without success:

```
query = 'SELECT codes CASE WHEN codes LIKE 'X10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as I10X FROM processed_data'

cur.execute(query)
```

Example data:

```
+--------------+
| codes   |    |
+--------------+
| X10, X11|    |
| x11, X9 |    |
| x10     |    |
| x13     |    |
+-------+------+
```

Example target data:

```
+----------+-----+
| codes    | X10 |
+----------+-----+
| X10, X11 |   1 |
| x11, X9  |   0 |
| x10      |   0 |
| x13      |   0 |
| x10      |   1 |
+-------+--------+
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to select the data in such a fashion or you actually want to alter the table?

Comment: I would like to alter the table such that there is a new column, in the example this would be 'X10'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to alter your `processed_data` table to add the `X10` column, and then you can update the `X10` field based on the `codes` field. For example:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()  # fetch a cursor from your SQLite connection

# let's first check if we already have the X10 column in our table
x10_exists = False
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(processed_data)")  # get info on the table
for column in cursor:
    if column[1] == 'X10':
        x10_exists = True
        break
if not x10_exists:  # if X10 doesn't exist...
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE processed_data ADD COLUMN X10")  # add the X10 column

cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE processed_data
    SET X10=CASE
        WHEN codes LIKE 'X10' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
''')  # update the values

db.commit()  # commit the transaction
```

Comment: first check whether there is column x10 exist or not then execute alter table.

Comment: Thank you! I added %X10% incase anyone uses this as reference as there were a few strings in the codes column

Comment: @avocet - regarding altering an already altered table, I've added a check if the X10 column exists prior to altering it. It won't be popping up with that error of yours anymore.

Comment: Great addition Zwer. Wondering if the column could be dynamic. i.e. search across all columns in the database to find X10 match?

Comment: @avocet - well, you can technically use the `PRAGMA` query to get all the columns and then build the `UPDATE` case to check against all columns.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to project the data as you expecting or do you want actually create new column with the data itself.

first loop the rows and create the mapping column_codes,X10 mapping based on your criteria.
create the new column x10 when there is no such a column.
c.execute("alter table processed_data add column 'x10' 'INTEGER' default 0 ")

execute an update query for  column_codes,X10.

Comment: Providing I understand your question correctly, I would like to import the complete table with the new column into Python. I am not concerned about storing it in the database as the code will change.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the result you asked, without actually creating a column, use

```
select *, codes like 'x10' from codes;
```

Comment: I see you also wanted to create the column, I think others are helping you on that